# Tar all folders and files except folders with a specific name

Tags: unix, tar

Im trying to tar a folder with subdirectories but i want to exclude all folders with the name "log".

I have search and seen that the tar command have the option of --exclude the problem is that this option required to be specific folder not a dynamic one.

Is there any other way?

so far the command i have is:

```
tar czf ROOT/backup/servers/20150504.tar.gz ./servers --exclude=".*log.*"
```

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic directory? You do know that you can have multiple --exclude, right?, i.e. `tar czf something.tar.gz ./dir --exclude=log --exclude=log*`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to exclude all folders with the name "log", probably using -X is more convenient. Here is an example:

```
$ find ./servers -type -d -name *log* > excludefiles
$ tar czf ROOT/backup/servers/20150504.tar.gz -X excludefiles ./servers
```